# Can't install python-httplib2 in Centos 6?

Tags: centos, yum

For some reason my Centos 6 (running in a Vagrant box) won't find any `httplib2` package, while [it definitely looks like it exists](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/31335492/dir/centos_6/com/python-httplib2-0.7.7-1.el6.noarch.rpm.html).

```
vagrant@localhost ~ $ yum search httplib
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: be.mirror.guru
 * extras: be.mirror.guru
 * updates: be.mirror.guru
Warning: No matches found for: httplib
No Matches found

vagrant@localhost ~ $ sudo yum install python-httplib2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: be.mirror.guru
 * extras: be.mirror.guru
 * updates: be.mirror.guru
No package python-httplib2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Other packages (git for instance) can be found without any issue.  What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it was the right way to proceed, but I solved my issue by installing [EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL):

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
```

> The EPEL repository is managed by the EPEL group, which is a Special
>   Interest Group within the Fedora Project. The ‘EPEL’ part is an
>   abbreviation that stands for Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux. The
>   EPEL group creates, maintains and manages a high quality set of
>   additional packages. These packages may be software not included in
>   the core repository, or sometimes updates which haven’t been provided
>   yet.
>   [Source](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-epel-repository/)

And there the httplib2 package is available:

```
$ sudo yum -y install python-pip
```